# How to get HostBuilderContext from Extension method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a simple extension method which is called as follows in program.cs.  I have just put here the most important parts of the code.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
        {
        })
    .ConfigureCustomLogger((ctx,settings)=> {
        settings = ctx.Configuration.GetSection("LogSettings").Get<LogSettings>();
    });
```

Extesnion method

```
public static IHostBuilder ConfigureCustomLogger(this IHostBuilder builder, Action<HostBuilderContext,LogSettings> configuration)
{
    var logSettings = new LogSettings();
    configuration(/*instance of HostBuilderContext*/,logSettings);
}
```

Not sure how to get the instance of HostBuilderContext?
Basically the method is suppose to populate logSettings.

Answer (score 2):

As in the implementation of ConfigureLogging from Microsoft (https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs,226edc6eec27581b) you can use ConfigureServices:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder ConfigureCustomLogger(this IHostBuilder builder, Action<HostBuilderContext, LogSettings> configuration)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices((ctx, collection) =>
    {
        var logSettings = new LogSettings();
        configuration(ctx, logSettings);
    });
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: I did see that but did not use it because I assumed it was a custom logger and the point point I was looking for is what if it was not a Logger and I just needed HostBuilderContext for something else?

Comment: You can use the ConfigureServices method to get the HostBuilderContext (ctx) and read your appsettings.json. If you don't touch the collection parameter to add services in your logic it doesn't matter.

Comment: Again you are correct.  I am just thinking WHERE/HOW the context can be injected if I did not want to use the extension methods provided.  I went through the implementation quickly but did not figure out how that context could be passed from program.cs from anywhere else its simple as passing it using DI but from program.cs its not.